# how to store the result of each iteration of for loop into an array in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
d1=[[0],[1]]
fnet1=[[-0.8420],[-0.8841]]

for i in range(len(d1)):
    s=(d1[i]-fnet1[i])
    print "s:",s
    t=(1-np.power(fnet1[i],2))
    print "t:",t
    m=np.dot(s,t)
    deltaO=np.dot((0.5),m)
    print "deltaO:",deltaO
```

I expect answer like `deltaO=[[0.1225],[0.2057]]` but I am getting the answer in different form like `deltaO=[[0.1225]]` and `deltaO=[[0.2057]]` if I use `print deltaO`. But I want both answers in one matrix. In this `print "deltaO:",deltaO,` statement in the for loop show only one value.

Comment: Your example code dos not work: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'`. Please provide working code.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `for` statement, define `deltaO` as an empty list (matrix). Change the other `deltaO` line (ln10) to `deltaO.append(np.dot((0.5),m))`, and the next to `print "deltaO:",deltaO[-1]`.

It should print the most recent entry and keep the others.